# Android Studio Logcat doesn't show http calls, even if you filter by http

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been into an issue with logcat for a while, which doesn't get me any info about the different http my app invoke.

I get into a workaroud using Log.d(), and the info by some custom filter, but some days ago after updating Android Studio to Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1, start to get nothing from Logcat.

I would like to know if the issue is related with the IDE, or can be related which I'm using corrutines to manage my http call, using LaunchEffect in severals calls, and the viewModelScope in other.

It's a little bit weird due to some mounth ago AS show me the http log always, even I don't add a Log.d().

Take thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I am also facing this issue and after lot of try i got succeed.So, i request you to try below the code and filter by "**okhttp**".so,you're able to see **URL** and **response** both.

   ```
   static Retrofit getClient() {
           HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
           interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
           OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                   .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                   //.addInterceptor(REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR)
                   .addNetworkInterceptor(new Interceptor() {

                       @Override

                       public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                           Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                                   // .addHeader(Constant.Header, authToken)
                                   .build();
                           return chain.proceed(request);
                       }
                   }).build();

           final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                   .baseUrl(Const.DURISIMO_MUSIC)
                   .client(client) // This line is important
                   .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                   .build();
       return retrofit;
   }
   ```